# jQuery .each returning TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, indexof

What I'm trying to do is find all of the links on a page that contain https and if they do, do something. However, when I run this in Chrome using console, I get a Type Error: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of null. I've read on SO that if a value is returned as undefined, then it breaks the function. So I'm wondering how do I ignore https that do not have a value for onclick? (btw, I'm slowly learning javascript/jquery). Thanks

```
$("a[href*='https:']").each(function(){
    var blah = $(this).attr('onclick');

    console.log(blah);

    if(blah.indexOf('_gaq') === 0){
        console.log('contains gaq');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the selector

```
$("a[href*='https:'][onclick]")
```

To select only anchor tags that have both 'https' in their href, and 'onclick' attributes.

Ref: [Multiple Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/)

Comment: I had (this) and copied it wrong when I put it into SO; I've updated it. Thanks

Comment: I've removed it from my answer. The selector issue was the important part, in any case.

Comment: I'd agree with you, ThinTim. The multiple attribute selector was new for me. Thanks for the documentation.

Comment: Ended up doing `$("a[href*='https:'][onclick*='_gaq']")`

Comment: Good solution.  I actually forgot to mention that using `$("a[href*='https:'][onclick]")` doesn't guarantee that the onclick attribute has anything in it, it just guarantees that it's there.  So `<a href="https:" onclick></a>` would be accepted, and `blah` would be set to `""` (empty string).  Your solution covers all cases though :)

Answer (score 2):

Check that `blah` exists first:

```
$("a[href*='https:']").each(function () {
    var blah = $(this).attr('onclick');

    if (blah && blah.indexOf('_gaq') === 0) {
        console.log('contains gaq');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there is no `onclick` defined for some `<a>`. You can add the logic to check whether `onclick` exists or not.

```
$("a[href*='https:']").each(function () {
    var blah = $(this).attr('onclick');

    if (blah !== undefined) {
        if (blah.indexOf('_gaq') === 0) {
            console.log('contains gaq');
        }
    }
});
```